# Make wave texture only appear at top of mesh? (Grilled Steak)

Tags: texturing, materials

As seen below, I have a material with a wave texture applied over it. However, I'd like to have the wave texture only appear at the top of the mesh to represent grill marks, like grill marks found at the top of a filet mignon. Is it possible to subtract part of the wave texture so it only appears at the top of the mesh? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you want the limit to be clear (in that case, Chris' answer si good) or smooth (in that case you need to create a mask between top and side faces, procedurally or with an image)?

Comment: @moonboots Hi! I'm looking for a smooth transition please. If you have a link or an answer on how to do the smooth mask method, please feel free to share it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create 2 different textures (here the wave texture and the pure brown texture) and mix them with a vertical black and white gradient as mask (use the *Texture Coordinate Generated* output, plug it into a *Converter > Separate XYZ* node that you plug into the factor of the *Mix Shader*):

[image]

Comment: Very nice! 

Comment: thanks, the other solutions would have been to use Vertex Paint as mask (but you need a bit of topology) or an Image Texture as mask

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly! Thanks to Chris too for your recommendation. :)

Answer (score 8):

As the normal of your surface approaches alignment with the Z axis, the absolute of its dot-product with (0,0,1) approaches 1, (from 0). So you can map a range of that to 0->1 to create a mask between stripes and  no-stripes:

[image]

If you use the Normal, it has a nice side-effect of putting a tiny  bit of char in any nobbles there may be in the sides of your patty..

[image]

The Normal output of *Texture Coordinate* is in Object space, so you can flip your burger OK.

Comment: damn Robin, does this have to be!?!?!? NOW i am hungry!!!!

Comment: I hope it's vegan

Comment: I don't think it will be up to OP's standards... they want _Filet Mignon_, apparently.. :)

Comment: @moonboots It does look disappointingly Vegan.. :( .. It would take a bit of time to tweak little pools of fat, dripping juices, pinkness in the middle...

Comment: Awesome solution @RobinBetts! That works great too! Really nice burger, btw. :)

Comment: @Chris don't eat vertices!!

Comment: Do you think they have too much kcal?